# How to solve these error messages from nav2d tutorials

Tags: ros, navigation, nav2d, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone.

I try to do the tutorials from nav2D and when I run the tutirialX.launch I get these errors:

```
[ERROR] [1412367505.742519058, 35.800000000]: Failed to send PAUSE_COMMAND to Navigator.
[ERROR] [1412367510.758595622, 40.800000000]: Failed to send STOP_COMMAND to Navigator.
[ERROR] [1412367517.638542157, 47.700000000]: Failed to send GETMAP_COMMAND to GetMap-Client.
[ERROR] [1412367517.982605682, 48.000000000]: Failed to send EXPLORE_COMMAND to Explore-Client.
```

I don't know I get these errors, so I would apreciate if someone could help me with this. I wanna post another question from this package: nad2D_localizer need a topic that publishes odometry information or not?

Thank you in advance for any answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194167/how-to-solve-these-error-messages-from-nav2d-tutorials./) by [ingcavh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20373/ingcavh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ingcavh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20373/ingcavh/) on 2014-11-05**:
Yes sir, that was the problem. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you check if navigator, get_map_client and explore_client are running? These errors indicate that service calls are failing, which might also be due to communication problems with your ROS setup.

The localizer takes odometry data from tf (odom -> map).

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2